# How to properly draw an icon through text inside an element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have inspected a lot of buttons using a technique where their icon
is defined by text through the "before" pseudo-element, something like
this:

```
element:before {
    content: "\e604";
}
```

That code is suposed to draw a star.

I added that to my code, but the icon is not drawn.

```
.button {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    background-color: #00bcd4;
    position: relative;
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.button:before {
    content:"\e604";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/egeszqw6/

What should I do to make the icon appear?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `.admin__add:before` to `.button:before` it's always good to understand what you are copying and pasting. `.admin__add` element does not exist in your markup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is actually showing up is a font.

```
 content:"\e604";
```

The statement above will just render the glyph (or char) that relates to the \e604 unicode.

So, unless you specifically have a font specified and included (Such as [glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) or [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), used by bootstrap) or a custom font made at sites like [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/). It will not work. You need to specify the font-face!

Comment: Yes, the given code is from ICOMOON for the trash-can or the delete icon.

Answer (score 1):

In your example fiddle, you missed the class on the button. It should be this:

```
<div class="button admin__add"></div>
```

Other than that, you need to set the font-family in the `.admin__add:before` css

I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egeszqw6/1/), using font awesome as an example